# How to fix Fetch request to Node.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to do a simple POST request using fetch. I'm trying to create a contact form using Vanilla Javascript, HTML, CSS on the front end and Node.js / Express on the backend. Here's my front end code:

```
            <form id="sendMail">
                <div>
                  <label for="name">Name: </label>
                  <input name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
                <div>
                  <label for="email">Email: </label>
                  <input name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="phone">Phone: </label>
                    <input name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone">
                  </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="subject">Message: </label>
                    <input name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="How can we help you?">
                </div>
                <div>
                  <input type="submit">Send Message</input>
                </div>
            </form> 

<script>
  document.getElementById("sendMail").addEventListener('submit', sendMail);

  function sendMail(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    let email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    let phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
    let subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;

    console.log("sendMail fired!", name, email, phone, subject);

    fetch('/api/contact', {
        method: 'POST', 
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({name: name, email: email, phone: phone, subject: subject}),
      })
    //   .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log('Success:', data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
  } 
</script>
```

Here is my code on the backend:

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("express"));

// default URL for website
app.use('/', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/express/index.html'));
    //__dirname : It will resolve to your project folder.
  });

const server = http.createServer(app);
const port = 4040;

const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

app.post('/api/contact', async(req, res, next) => {
  const { name, email, phone, subject } = req.body;
  console.log("sendMail fired: ", req.body, name, email, phone, subject);

  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'gmail',
      auth: {
          user: 'myEmailAddress',
          pass: 'myPassword',
      }
  });

  let mailOptions = await transporter.sendMail({
      from: `info@companyemailaddress`,
      to: `${email}`,
      subject: `company`,
      text:
          `${name}, \n\n` +
          `Thank you for contacting company! A representative will contact you within 2 business days. \n\n` +
          `If you have any further question, feel free to email us at:  \n\n` +
          `info@company \n\n` +
          `- company Automated Message`
  });

  console.log('Message sent: %s', mailOptions.messageId);
  // console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(mailOptions))

  let mailOptions2 = await transporter.sendMail({
    from: `info@companyemail address`,
    to: `myEmail`,
    subject: `company`,
    text:
        `Name: ${name}, \n\n` +
        `Email: ${email}, \n\n` +
        `Phone: ${phone}, \n\n` +
        `Subject: ${subject}, \n\n`
  });

  console.log('Message sent: %s', mailOptions2.messageId);

  res.send('Email sent!')   
})


server.listen(port);

console.debug('Server listening on port ' + port);
```

When I click the "submit" input on the front end, I get a successful response without any server error messages, but when I look at my server console.logs, it shows nothing - as if the server has not been touched. If I just send an object in the body of the post request that is not JSON.stringify(), the server DOES give error messages saying that there's an issue with the object in the body. So it looks like the POST request is successfully contacting the server. But nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you change your root route from `app.use` to `app.get` i.e `app.get('/', ..`. Let me know if that works?

Comment: use return in your responses : return res.send("")

Comment: @dhruwlalan That worked! If you submit it as an answer, I'll select it as the answer. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your **root** route from `app.use` to `app.get`

when you use `app.use` on `/` it matches **any routes** with **any http verb** and acts as a **global middleware**.

Therefore your post request was actually getting matched by that `app.use` & your actual `app.post` never got chance to execute.

Answer (score 0):

You can test yor api with postman then generate the fetch request for you.
in your case you should put the full uri as args to your fetcch call.

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
```

.then(response => response.json())
.then(console.log);